# FT232RL out of sync

Tags: arduino, atmega, avrdude

Hi I have a FT232RL board that I'm trying to use to program an arduino (ATmega328p). Ive tried to use the arduino IDE to upload the sketch but it keeps giving me programmer not responding. I also tried to use avrdude from the command line and that gave me:

> avrdude -p m328p -c stk500v1 -P com4 -b 115200
>
> avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00

I have tried multiple baudrates and still same thing.

When its trying to upload I do see a light blink which I presume to be the Rx but don't see the Tx one light.

Here is the link to the  [board](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HXT8DZ4) I am using.

Comment: BAUD rates are matching?

Comment: I believe so, what would it have to match with if I wanted to check?

Comment: And you have connected rx to tx and tx to rx?

Comment: That is correct, but I finally got it to work

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing and playing around with the the chips, I found out what the problem was. When trying to upload a sketch to the atmega it was placed in the arduino board. Everything was wired up correctly even added a 100nf Cap for the reset and still nothing, but apparently with the arduino board I had to hold the reset till the IDE said uploading and for avrdude when I hit enter. I then tried this on my DIY arduino board and I didnt have to hit the reset button... Anyways it was just a bootloader timing problem.

> avrdude -cstk500v1 -pm328p -Pcom4 -b115200 -U flash:w:Test.hex -F

This is the avrdude command line command I used to get it working.
Thanks for everyones help